# How to start a marquee just from where it ends?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML marquee. I want to start the marquee again just from where it ends.

[image: 1]

---

[image: 2]

And, my HTML code is:

```
<marquee width="450px" height="450px" direction="up" scrollamount="3" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">

CONTENT

</marquee>
```

Comment: can you post your html code as well ?

Comment: @PardeepPathania It's already there.

Comment: @PardeepPathania Below the images.

Comment: did you create the same imaged html ?

Comment: try  this 

<marquee width="450px" BEHAVIOR="ALTERNATE" height="450px" direction="up" scrollamount="3" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">

CONTENT

</marquee>

Comment: marquee is obsolete, as stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee. You should use css transitions instead

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do just that using the HTML marquee tag - it must have JavaScript added for that purpose.
This might help you
[Text and Image Crawler by John Scheuer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm)

Comment: I knew that. I just wanted to know if I could do it using `<marquee>` tag or not.